# Cocoa Touch Framework library - versions and memory distribution

Tags: ios, cocoa, frameworks

I am going to create a Cocoa Touch Framework library and I am confused how they work on iOS. What would happen if there are different apps installed on a device that use different versions of that library?
Would each app has access to its own version of the framework or they will share some single version of it? 
How would that single version would be determined then?

Logically thinking each app should own its own version, but I am not sure how frameworks and dynamic libraries work on iOS. Thanks for the help.